# Add Properties in setBackgroundImag and Serialize canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, serialization, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have two doubts:

https://jsfiddle.net/2h5nbrr2/1/

**1. How I insert properties in background image:**

```
 function backchange(img)
{ 
 var imag = img.src;  
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(imag, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}
```

I trying, but this is not working:

```
 function backchange(img)
{ 
 var imag = img.src;  
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(imag, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
width: 700,
height: 500,


);
}
```

**2.  I not undertand how to apply serialize (json and svg test) for all objects and background, in my example**

returns always:

```
{"objects":[],"background":""}
```

I am using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)

Thanks for any help

Comment: #1. Your options argument must be an object: `... canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), { width: 700,height: 500 } ...` #2. You can use [`canvas.toJSON`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON) to serialize most scene elements.

Comment: #1 thank you so much its works, #2 I trying `$('jsson').onclick = function() {  
var json = canvas.toJSON();
alert(json);
};` not working return: `[object object]`[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h5nbrr2/2/)

Comment: JSON.stringify(json) if you want to alert it.

Comment: Thank you it works, If you want you can create an answer and I mark as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your options argument must be an object:

   function backchange(img){ 
       var imag = img.src;
       canvas.setBackgroundImage(
           imag,
           canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas).
           {width: 700,height: 500}
       );
   }
2. You can use `var json=canvas.toJSON ...` to serialize most scene elements. As @AndreaBogazzi says, if you want to view the JSON you can: `alert(JSON.stringify(json))`